# Share column width between Grids in items of an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, grid, sharedsizegroup

I'm writing a control to display and edit objects in a form. The control (`FormDataView`) is an `ItemsControl` where each item is a `FormField` control made of a `Grid`, with the field name in the left column and the editor (e.g. TextBox) in the right column. In order to align the editors, I want the first column in each `Grid` to share the same width.

So I tried to use `IsSharedSizeScope` and `SharedSizeGroup`, but it doesn't work, the first column has a different width in each `FormField`.

Here are the styles for these controls:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctl:FormDataView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type ItemsControl}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                            Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                            IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctl:FormField}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctl:FormField}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="headerColumn" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      Margin="3"
                                      TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                      Name="PART_Display"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding DisplayTemplate}"
                                      Margin="2"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                      Name="PART_Editor"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding EditorTemplate}"
                                      Margin="2"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInEditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ctl:FormDataView}}}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Display" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Editor" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notice how `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` is set in the `ItemsPanel` of `FormDataView`, while `SharedSizeGroup` is set in the template of `FormField`. This correctly expresses what I want to do: each `FormField` should use the same width for the first column. However, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) for the `SharedSizeGroup` property, this scenario is not supported:

> Grid size-sharing does not work if you set IsSharedSizeScope to true
>   within a resource template and you define SharedSizeGroup as outside
>   that template.

OK, so I can understand why it doesn't work... but I don't know how to work around this limitation.

Any idea?

*N.B.: I don't want to assign a fixed width to the first column of course...*

Comment: Why don't you just use a GridView (a listview with columns)?

Comment: @Wallstreet Programmer, I could try that, if I find a way to hide the column headers... but I'd prefer a clean solution based on a Grid. Using a GridView seems overkill for my needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I have no access to my Visual Studio Enviroment so I couldnt check the following tips...

1. Assign `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` to `FormDataView` itself and not to the `ItemsPanel`. Do you really need `StackPanel` as the items panel? cant you live without that?

See if the above change works first...

1. if not then revamp your item level code and assign `SharedSizeGroup="headerColumn"` in your item data template of your `FormDataView` and not in the `ControlTemplate` of individual `FormField`.

Let me know if this helps....